# Git :Constantly adding thing from one branch to another

Tags: git

I have a program develop by the company i work for.This program is in TFS and get update daily.I maintaining a version of this program where my update are not integrated in the main branch (TFS ).I am trying to have to branch in git, Master which is a copy of the TFS manually pull every day and mine, i need to add the change i don't have from the master to mine but by checking every conflict all the time.How can i do that ? I look at rebase but could't make it work. Bellow a schema of what i am looking to do.

[image: GitIssue]

Comment: I think you need to explain why merging doesn't work for you

Comment: When i merge on to the other i can' see the conflict part where i could choose which version to use.